# SSRS Deploy Doesnt work

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012

Please help, I am editing some of my reports in SSRS, but when I wanted to redeploy it, it doestn work, I mean it just say "Deploy Start" and immediately pops up another message "Ready". it should say "Deploy Succeeded".

Comment: Are you seeing this in the "Output" window in visual studio? If not, check there. Sometimes the status bar switches back to saying "Ready" quickly, but that doesn't necessarily mean nothing happened. I assume you've confirmed the deploy is not working by running the report from the server, and confirming your changes are not there?

Comment: build it in visual studio, and open your deploy server url and you can directly diploy the build rdl file there

Comment: Are you going by the messages on the Output or have you checked the Report Manager? also check your Target URL path.